# fetching data from mongodb and find closest value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, fetch

**My code look like this:**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ourDataSchema = new Schema ({
   rank : Number,
   totalPoints : Number
});

const rankTotalpoint = mongoose.model("rankTotalpoint", ourDataSchema);

    const ourData = [
     {rank :1, totalPoints  : 2000},
     {rank :2, totalPoints  : 1980},
     {rank :3, totalPoints  : 1940},
     {rank :4, totalPoints  : 1890},
     {rank :5, totalPoints  : 1830},
     {rank :6, totalPoints  : 1765}
];

rankTotalpoint.create(ourData, function (error) {
    console.log('saved!');
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
...
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I fetch a **rank** by it's **totalPoint**?

   - I tried `find()` but it didn't work, I guess I'm using it in a wrong way.
2. I'm getting an input(Number) from user, I want to match the number with the **totalPoint**(if exists) that we fetched from our database *and return it's rank*, and if the exact number didn't exist, I want to match it with the closest totalPoint in our database and return the rank as a response.

Please at least answer my first question!

Highly appreciate your answers guys,
I'm STUCK!

Comment: What do you consider closest...  if a user inputs 1800 - should 1830 be returned or 1765?

Comment: this doesn't matter too much, I just want it to be matched with a totalPoint that i have and return the relevant rank

Comment: I have supplied an answer - please let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much mate, that was exactly what I was looking for! It works perfectly on live demo, but when I tested it in my project with postman, it didn't return anything, I'm posting my codes with details as an answer here, please check it out. Appreciate your kind answers mate I was really stuck :)

Comment: Please see my updated answer. (adding here as well, in case people see this thread and not the other one)

Answer (score 0):

***Question #1:***

To find a rank by its totalPoint, you can do:

You can check out a [live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PerCZ1kC_ME)

```
db.collection.find({
  totalPoints: 2000 // <<<------------------ The exact value you want to find
},
{
  _id: 0,
  rank: 1
})
```

---

***Question #2:***

To find *closest* rank, by a user supplied totalPoints value, you should be able to use the following query...

You can check out a [live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VIte5WyqNxb)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      diff: {
        $abs: {
          $subtract: [
            1800, // <<<----------------------- THIS IS THE USER SUPPLIED VALUE
            "$totalPoints"
          ]
        }
      },
      doc: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      diff: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      rank: "$doc.rank"
    }
  }
])
```

---

***UPDATE/FINAL ANSWER:***

Your issue is because Mongoose is promise/async based. You are not awaiting anything, so your code returns a variable that has not been set yet by your query..

I was testing using 2 files: `myMongoose.js` and `index.js`..

```js
// myMongoose.js

// ** CODE THAT SAVES DATA TO DATABASE HAS BEEN REMOVED FOR BREVITY **

require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const RankTotalpointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  rank: Number,
  totalPoints: Number
});

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const mongoConnection = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_DB_STRING, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
});

const RankTotalpoint = mongoConnection.model("RankTotalpoint", RankTotalpointSchema, 'Testing');

/**
 * ~~~~~~ **** THIS HAS TO BE AN ASYNC FUNCTION **** ~~~~~~
 */
exports.result = async function (param) {
  const finalresult = await RankTotalpoint.aggregate([{
      $project: {
        diff: {
          $abs: {
            $subtract: [
              param, // <<<----------------------- THIS IS THE USER SUPPLIED VALUE 
              "$totalPoints"
            ]
          }
        },
        doc: "$$ROOT"
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        diff: 1
      }
    },
    {
      $limit: 1
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        rank: "$doc.rank"
      }
    }
  ])
  return finalresult;
};
```

...and then in `index.js`:

```js
// index.js

const { result } = require('./myMongoose');

// Use it like this:
async function init() {
    try {
        const d = await result(1800);
        console.log(d);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

init(); // -> [ { rank: 5 } ]

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

// ...or like this:
(async () => {
    try {
        const d = await result(1800);
        console.log(d); // -> [ { rank: 5 } ]
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})()

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

// ...or like this:
result(1800)
    .then(d => console.log(d)) // -> [ { rank: 5 } ]
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

**These are my controller file codes where I'm getting the user input** *and passed it to the code that you send me which I put them in my model files.*

```
const express = require('express');

const model = require('../model/logic');

exports.index = (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({message : 'INSERT INPUTS HERE'});
    };


  exports.getUserData = (req, res, next) => {
     const literature = req.body.literature * 4;
     const arabic = req.body.arabic * 2;
     const religion = req.body.religion * 3;
     const english = req.body.english * 2;
     const math = req.body.math * 4;
     const physics = req.body.physics * 3;
     const chemistry = req.body.chemistry *2;
     const TOTALPOINT = literature + arabic + religion + english + math + physics + chemistry;

     let result = model.result(TOTALPOINT);
     res.status(200).json(result); 
  };
```

**And this is my model/logic file which I imported them into controller above:**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ourDataSchema = new Schema ({
   rank : Number,
   totalPoints : Number
});

const rankTotalpoint = mongoose.model("rankTotalpointData", ourDataSchema);

const ourData = [
     {rank : 1, totalPoints   : 2000},
     {rank : 2, totalPoints   : 1980},
     {rank: 3,  totalPoints   : 1940},
     {rank:4, totalPoints    : 1890},
     {rank :5, totalPoints   : 1830},
     {rank : 6, totalPoints  : 1765},
     {rank : 7, totalPoints  : 1600}
 ];


rankTotalpoint.create(ourData, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    else {
        console.log('saved!');
    }
});


exports.result = function (param) {
    const finalResult = rankTotalpoint.aggregate([
        {
          $project: {
            diff: {
              $abs: {
                $subtract: [
                  param, // <<<----------------------- THIS IS THE USER SUPPLIED VALUE
                  "$totalPoints"
                ]
              }
            },
            doc: "$$ROOT"
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            diff: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            rank: "$doc.rank"
          }
        }
      ])
   return finalResult;
}
```

***When I'm testing my app with postman I get this response in there :***

```
{
    "_pipeline": [
        {
            "$project": {
                "diff": {
                    "$abs": {
                        "$subtract": [
                            16,
                            "$totalPoints"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "doc": "$$ROOT"
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "diff": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "$limit": 1
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "rank": "$doc.rank"
            }
        }
    ],
    "options": {}
}
```